# Split line in `legend` with `pgfplots`

Tags: pgfplots, legend

In the following plot, how can I split the red line of the caption into a red line and a blue dashed line (so that the total length of the red-blue segment is that of the green one)?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot [green,domain=-1:1] {x};
    \legend{$f_1$}
    \addplot [red,domain=-1:0] {x^3};
    \addplot [blue,domain=0:1] {x^2};
    \addlegendimage{blue}
    \addlegendentry{$f_2$}

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility using `legend image code/.code` and `\addlegendimage` to provide the desired variation of the default `line legend` style:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[legend entries={$f_1$,$f_2$},]
    \addlegendimage{no markers,green}
    \addplot [green,domain=-1:1,forget plot] {x};
    \addplot [red,domain=-1:0,forget plot] {x^3};
    \addplot [blue,dashed,domain=0:1,forget plot] {x^2};
    \addlegendimage{legend image code/.code={
      \draw[red] plot coordinates {(0cm,0cm) (0.3cm,0cm)};
      \draw[blue,dashed] plot coordinates {(0.3cm,0cm) (0.6cm,0cm)};
      }
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On page 210 of the `pgfplots` manual there's the definition for the line legend style:

```
\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/line legend/.style={
    legend image code/.code={
      \draw[mark repeat=2,mark phase=2,##1]
        plot coordinates {
          (0cm,0cm)
          (0.3cm,0cm)
          (0.6cm,0cm)
      };%
    }
  }
}
```

so the length for the line is `0.6cm`.

Comment: I think you can delete the two lines with `\mybox`. Thank you, I'm going to try it "in situ" now. How do you know that the length of the line in `legend` is 6mm?

Comment: @anderstood Yes, those lines of code were just a leftover. I've deleted them. The length is given in the `line legend` style whose definition is on page 210 of the `pgfplots` documentation )for version 1.12.1).